# Centering two elements responsively with definite gap

Tags: html, css

For a particular layout that I am creating, I am required to center two elements horizontally in a div as though they were a single element as shown in this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtvGh.jpg

Between these two, I also need to have a gap (as shown above) that remains definite even the the browser window width changes.

What would be the best way to do this with css?

I tried doing this floats inside the div but could not get the gap between the elements to be the same responsively.

I have also done some research online but in vain.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, if you have any questions, let me know.

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
}
.left img {
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://bigcatrescue.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/tigersnikita.jpg" alt="Tiger image" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h1>Get to know us a little better!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet libero at odio tristique elementum non a sem. Proin dui nulla, cursus sed purus ac, consectetur ultricies purus. Vivamus turpis lectus, dapibus sit amet vulputate dictum, commodo at metus. Integer ornare vehicula velit, ac feugiat enim egestas vitae. Nam a ornare leo. Curabitur hendrerit neque lorem, a aliquam nisi rhoncus feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ullamcorper augue quis eros ultrices sagittis. Vestibulum dapibus dapibus efficitur.</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the table cell property do? Thanks a lot though.

Comment: It makes the `divs` to be displayed as a table, you can imagine a table with 1 row and 2 columns, what does it do? it keeps the divs (cells) fixed width.
The box-sizing property is what's causing the resize.